# In Java why would you assign a variable to itself

Tags: java

I am learning Java at University but I am struggling to understand why you would assign a variable to itself inside a constructor.

This is example code:

```
private String name;
private int age;
private boolean student;
private char gender;


public Person(String name, int age, boolean student, char gender)
{
    this.setName(name);
    this.age = age;
    this.student = student;

}
```

I am struggling to understand the purpose of 'this.age = age' and 'this.student = student'. These values are already assigned to whatever they hold so why would you need to do that? My only theory is that it is to initialize the variable but I'm not sure.

Comment: No they are not. You are assigning the values of your constructor's arguments to your instance fields. So the `name` etc. passed by the caller to the constructor goes to populate your own instance's `name` (or `this.name` if you will).

Comment: They are two different variables. `this.age` is the class variable, while `age` is the one that's passed to the constructor (it's alive only there - on its scope).

Comment: They are not the same scope try `System.identityHashCode(this.age);` vs. `System.identityHashCode(age);` PS. you forgot your class definition in your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not assigning the variable to itself, `this.VAR` and `VAR` are different variables.

When using a class in Java, you can refer to your attributes by using the `this` prefix. In many methods the `this` prefix is optional because there is not any method parameter with the same name. However, when a method has variables that have the same name than the class attributes, it is mandatory to use the `this` prefix to differentiate between the class attribute and the method parameters (otherwise the most local variable - the method parameter - hides the most global one - the class attribute).

So when you are using:

```
this.age = age
```

you are initializing your class attribute to the value of the method parameter called `age`.

Notice that you can avoid using the `this` prefix if the method parameters have always different names than the class attributes:

```
private String name;
private int age;
private boolean student;
private char gender;    

public Person(String name, int ageParam, boolean studentParam, char genderParam){
    setName(name);
    age = ageParam;
    student = studentParam;
    gender = genderParam;    
}
```

Personally, I think that using the `this` prefix is more polite because you can quickly look if you are modifying your class attributes and the method parameters preserve its useful name (which is better to document and understand the code).

Comment: In my current project all parameters have to use the prefix "in" to be easier distinguishable from class and local declared variables, like:
public Person(String inName, int inAge, boolean inStudent, char inGender)... Good and easy readability is a very important factor on good and clean code.

Comment: @SCI That also seems a good convention as long as you use it for all the project :D

Answer (score 1):

This is only because of naming conventions that you have this, in fact this is 100% the same :

```
private String name;
private int age;
private boolean student;
private char gender;    

public Person(String nnn, int aaa, boolean sss, char ggg){
    this.setName(nnn);
    this.age = aaa;
    this.student = sss;
    this.gender = ggg;    
}
```

But with this, `this.` becomes useless, because `age = a;` is ok, that's why when there is a misunderstand possible you use `this.` to precise that it's the attribute of the class, different of the parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The critical point here is that there are *two* variables called `age`.  The first is the local variable which is a parameter to the constructor; the second is the instance variable of the `Person` class.

Inside the constructor, the parameter *hides* the instance variable, so just writing `age` will always refer to the parameter.  However, if you write `this.age`, you must be referring to the instance variable.  Thus:

```
this.age = age
```

assigns the value of the constructor parameter to the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

`this.age = age` , `this.age` is the variable associated with class Person's object (this keyword refers to the class' object reference) , and `age` is a local variable (it's scope is just within constructor definition) whose value that you are passing in the constructor to be assigned to the object's variable.

So when you call class's constructor when creating object :

Person p = new Person("name",22,true,'M');

the p object's age will be set as 22 .

If you would have used :

```
public Person(String name, int yearsOld, boolean student, char gender)
{
    this.setName(name);
    age = yearsOld; 
//here you could avoid using this since local variable name is different and age will refer to class level's age .
    this.student = student;

}
```